# Wakelock only works once

Tags: java, android

I created a Service that catches incoming notifications. Whenever a whatsapp notification appears the screen should be woken up and an activity is started. This works fine the first time, but then the screen just stays in sleep mode and the activity runs when I unlock the phone.

The Service Code:
I declare the variables here:

```
@TargetApi(26)
public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    public PowerManager pm;
    public PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
```

the wakelock code in the onCreate function:

```
pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "callOverlay:wakeScreenNotification");
```

and in the onNotificationPosted function:
[getting the notification content etc...]

```
try {
    //wake up screen
    wl.acquire();
    //run activity
    dialogIntent.putExtra("SERVICE", "whatsapp");
    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {                              
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);
         }
    }, 600);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.i(TAG,"ERROR: "+e);
} finally {
    wl.release();
}
```

inside the activity I added following code inside the onCreate function:

```
final Window win= getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

I'm new to android development.
What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking it may be [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby). Do things improve if you [disable battery optimization](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/android-basics-disable-doze-app-standby-for-individual-apps-0168960/) or implement a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)?

Comment: thanks fo the hint, on my phone (huawei p smart) that desn't semm to fix the issue.
I am using a Foreground Service btw ;)

Comment: I see a potential problem: Your `WakeLock` is released immediately after it is acquired! You need to keep it going longer than that. You might find it convenient to `release()` it in the `onResume()` of the `Activity` you are opening, or just set a timer for 30 seconds and `release()` it then.

Comment: There seems to be an odd issue since when I use my phone to emulate the app everything is working fine, but once I start the App on my phone the activity only starts as soon as I unlock the screen

Comment: That's probably because your emulator isn't going to sleep, and your phone is. Unless you have your phone plugged in. If that's the case, I'll withdraw this statement.

Comment: Another potential problem: Those window flags only work if they're being _set_. In other words, if they're already set, and you re-apply them, nothing happens. You've got to find an opportunity to remove them, at some point.

Comment: thanks for the help! I think the problem is, that my phone's cpu goes to sleep and isn't waking up with the Wakelock

Comment: Well, what of the fact that you're holding the `WakeLock` for less than 1ms? See 3rd comment from top.

Comment: I added wl.acquire(30000); to keep it alive for 30 seconds (I removed the release part in finaly of course), but it shows the same behavior

Comment: Alright, sounds like a good approach. Talk to me about the window flags. You're resetting them in-between wake-up attempts?

Comment: no, i set the window flags inside the activitie's onCreate function and don't reset them

Comment: See 6th comment from top.

Comment: can I just set it in the onAttachedToWindow function and reset it in the onDestroy function?

Comment: Hmm I'm not 100% sure of the best place to do that. You want to set them at the moment you decide to turn the screen on. And you need to be sure to keep them there until the Activity has displayed. `onDestroy()` may not be called in a predictable fashion, and `onPause()` might get called spuriously, so honestly I'd set a `CountDownTimer` for 30 seconds, and reset them then.

Comment: since I only finish the aktivity with a button I just reset the flags inside the button press function, but still no success :/

Comment: I'm afraid I can't explain that. How about: could you log state changes to A.) the `WakeLock`, B.) the window flags, C.) activity `onResume()/onPause()`, and D.) the WhatsApp notifications, and post that log?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the flag combination

```
FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
```

only takes effect (turns on the screen & dismisses the keyguard) *once per Activity*. Contrary to my above comment, removing and re-applying the flags does not work.

If you want the screen/wake changes to take effect a second time, you have to create a new Activity, and apply the same flags to it.

If the user manually changes the phone state (by moving to another Activity or by turning the screen off/locking the phone), this also causes the flags to lose their effect.